# Pausing timer when app is in background state Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, appdelegate

My ViewController.swift

```
func startTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer().scheduleTimerWithTimerInvterval(1.0,target: self,selctor: Selector("couting"),userinfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func pauseTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    println("pausing timer")
}
```

and this is appDelegate.swift

```
func applicateWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    viewController().pauseTimer()
    println("closing app")
}
```

It is printing **pausing timer and closing app** but when I open again I see it never paused. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: Try out this control , hope this will help you. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/game-timer

Comment: that doesn't pauses when app is in background state

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to set an observer listening to when the application did enter background. Add the below line in your ViewController's viewDidLoad() method.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("myObserverMethod:"), name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Add the below function to receive the notification.

```
func myObserverMethod(notification : NSNotification) {
    println("Observer method called")

    //You may call your action method here, when the application did enter background.
    //ie., self.pauseTimer() in your case.
}
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: this is perfect Suresh, and i have to create a new observer when user comes back so i can resume the timer?

Comment: Yes, you have to create another observer listening to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and similarly you call the actions inside the observer as specified above.

Comment: Awesome! i created same func when user enters again then resume timer. its working nicely (y)

Comment: Please note that the syntax would be ```NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PlayViewController.myObserverMethod(_:)), name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
``` now (swift 2.3)

Comment: Perfect Solution!

Comment: I search this for 2 days, I set ```NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name:UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)``` in ```viewDidLoad```, when I enters app again, the timer is keep updating in previous paused time but no progress. Mean time, audio is continue to play. And I get this error when enter background ```Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 21 (0x15), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.```. With Xcode 11 and iOS 13.

Comment: You may have to extend the app's background execution time if you're doing any background task like the following. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time#overview

Comment: In my case I want to perform didEnterBackground for particular ViewController and this code works for whole application.

Answer (score 7):

Updated Answer for Swift 5:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver
              (self,
               selector: #selector(myObserverMethod),
               name:UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

@objc func myObserverMethod() {
    print("Write Your Code Here")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer by @Suresh in Swift 3

Set an observer listening to when the application did enter **background** in your ViewController's viewDidLoad() method.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myObserverMethod), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
```

Add the below function to receive the notification.

```
 func myObserverMethod(notification : NSNotification) {

   print("Observer method called")

  //You may call your action method here, when the application did enter background.
  //ie., self.pauseTimer() in your case.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer for Swift 4:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myObserverMethod), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}

@objc func myObserverMethod() {
    // Call your action method here, when the application did enter background.
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `super viewDidLoad()`

Comment: improvement Swift 4: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopTimersMethod), name:UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new object and calling `pauseTimer()` on it:

```
viewController().pauseTimer()   // This line causes issue viewController(), creates a new instance
```

Instead of creating new object, either you should pass that instance to AppDelegate and call pauseTimer() on existing object or Listen for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification in your view controller class and pause timer from there.

Comment: tried but it only does is "println("pausing timer")" and doesn't stop the timer

Comment: @djay: how did you passed the object ? Please read my answer once again

Comment: whats the correct code for **ApplicationWillEnterBackground** in swift?

Comment: @djay: if you are looking for notifications, check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification

Comment: You can create your timer in AppDelegate class and use it in your viewcontroller ... by this you can easily set your timer invalidate when application is in background .