# Why Does NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithInterval() Resume When App Becomes Active?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift2, nstimer

In my app I declare a timer:

```
entropy = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Where entropy is:

```
var entropy: NSTimer
```

Then, within ApplicationWillResignActive entropy is invalidated:

```
main.entropy.invalidate()
```

Where main is:

```
let main = ViewController()
```

But then, when the application becomes active, the timer resumes from where it last was when the app resigned active.

What am I missing here?

Regards, Brandon

Comment: Where are you initialising the timer. If the initialisation of timer is more than once, even though if you have only one instance, there will be temporary timers created which might cause the problems.

Comment: If the current timer is invalidated before a new one is initialized, does that count as multiple initializations?

Comment: No but if entropy is initialised again and again before invalidating, then that'll create multiple instances. So where did you initialise the entropy?

Comment: Then no, the only initialization is this: `
        if (commenceButton.currentTitle == "Start") {
            commenceButton.enabled = false
            commenceButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: .Normal)
            entropy = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            commenceButton.enabled = true
        }
        else {
            commenceButton.enabled = false
            entropy.invalidate()
            commenceButton.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
            commenceButton.enabled = true
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27700746/4418557

Basically, I needed to add observers to my ViewController. For more details click the link above.